# PHP SOAP - Passing parameters with same name

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap, parameters

I'm calling an API using php and SOAP. 
some parts of the request are like:

```
<fin:Customer>
 <fin1:Address>
 <fin1:City>City</fin1:City>
 <fin1:Country>CA</fin1:Country>
 </fin1:Address>
<fin:Customer>
```

Which is easy to do with arrays:

```
'Customer' => array(
                'Address' => array (
                'City' => $City,
                'Country' => $Country,
                ),
```

But my challenge is for this part:

```
<fin:Criterions>
 <fin:Criterion name="VALX">17</fin:Criterion>
 <fin:Criterion name="VALOP">1</fin:Criterion>
 <fin:Criterion name="VALLP">10</fin:Criterion>
 <fin:Criterion name="TMS">3</fin:Criterion>
```

Because all tags have the same name, and they also have a name parameter and a value. 
How can I pass that to SOAP API? 
Is it possible to use arrays?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to construct a request, send it and handle the response is to use a WSDL to PHP generator as it'll normally generate each class for every parameter you need to send (in addition to the response objects and the operations classes)

Knowing this, you'll be able to easily see how to pass these "duplicated" tags as it is certainly an array of object that you must pass,

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which should work fine,

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
'Criterions' => array(
           'Criterion' => array(
                            array('name'=> 'VALX' , '_'=> '17' ), 
                            array('name'=> 'VALOP' , '_'=> '1' ),  
                            array('name'=> 'VALLP' , '_'=> '10' ),      
                            array('name'=> 'TMS' , '_'=> '3' )
                     ));
```

Be sure to use underscore ('_'), if other values (e.g. val, value, etc) didn't work.

Might save someone's time and effort.